# Unlocking an Azure AD B2C local account

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

When using Azure AD B2C, with local accounts and email address as the username, is there any mechanism to:

1. Identify that an account is locked via API or the Azure portal
2. Manually unlock that account ahead of the lock expiry time, e.g. via portal/API
3. Identify the time at which a lock will expire, again via API or portal. For example, you may wish to advise a customer to retry after a certain time

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can access this lockout information using either the Azure Portal or the Azure AD Graph API.

Currently, as far as I know, a local account is locked from any new sign-ins for one minute after ten failed password sign-ins. The local account lockout is extended, after each subsequent failed password sign-in, for one minute initially and then longer subsequently.

A directory administrator can't unlock the a local account. They must wait for the lockout duration to expire.